# Google Drive hangs at "scanning web ..." forever

Tags: google-drive

Google Drive on my laptop hangs at "scanning web ..." for hours and seems to remain there forever. This happens only to my laptop. My desktop PC is fine. It just happens to me one fine day and I do not recall doing anything special to cause this problem.

Has anyone else met this problem with Google Drive and are there any steps to take to solve this problem?

Comment: You're talking about the Google Drive app on your PC? This would be a better question for [su].

Comment: Sorry. I will repost my question over there.

Comment: Please don't. I have voted to have this question migrated. Let's not end up with duplicate questions.

Comment: Sorry again. I have deleted the question which I just posted on Super User. Now, waiting for the question to be migrated. Thanks.

Comment: Google is [aware](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/drive/-DBtCURYlYY/CqH9fNbaR_wJ) of the issue and is currently working on a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a Google apps for business account. Tech Support could not help appart from pronmising a patch "sometime later". I worked around the problem by un-installing Drive and removing all local data, then by reinstalling it again.